# What is the mathematical derivation for no diffusion term in the mass continuity equation of the Navier-Stokes/Euler equations?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow, diffusion, navier-stokes

In this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/194733/) the fact that the mass continuity equation in a mixture of gases has no diffusion term, i.e.,
$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot(\rho\vec{v})=0$$
has been discussed. Nevertheless, I'm struggling to come up with a proof starting from the convection-diffusion-reaction equation for each species. It seems to me that the starting point should be
$$\frac{\partial n_{j}}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot(n_{j}\vec{v}_{j}-D_{j}\nabla n_{j})=S_{j}$$
where $\vec{v}_{j}$ as opposed to $\vec v$ denotes the convective velocity vector of species $j$. I can define $n_{j}=\omega_{j}n$ where $\omega_{j}$ denotes the partial fraction of the fluid/gas made by species $j$ and $n$ denotes total denisty such that
$$\sum_{j}\frac{\partial n_{j}}{\partial t}=\sum_{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\omega_{j}n)=\sum_{j}\omega_{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} n+\sum_{j}n\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \omega_{j}=\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}\sum_{j}\omega_{j}+n\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\sum_{j} \omega_{j}=\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}$$
I can go ahead with the same analysis for the convective term by defining
$$\vec v=\frac{\sum_{j}n_{j}\vec{v}_{j}}{n}$$ and since mass is not produced $\sum_{j}S_{j}=0$ for the source term but the cancellation of the diffusion term still eludes me. I would appreciate any help with this final part. I'm curious if [Maxwell-Stefan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Stefan_diffusion) relation is necessary here.

Comment: It seems to me the diffusion term should not be present in your first equation.  The diffusion term is supposed to represent diffusional transport relative to the mass average velocity v.

Comment: @ChetMiller Agreed. Apparently, in kinetic theory diffusion is defined based on the relative (average) velocity of species with respect to one another. For example, in a binary mixture with bulk velocity $\vec v$, $\vec{v}_{1}-\vec{v}_{2}=\vec{v}_{1}-\vec{v}+\vec{v}-\vec{v}_{2}=(\vec{v}_{1}-\vec{v})-(\vec{v}_{2}-\vec{v})$. Still, the $D_{j}\nabla n_{j}$ term seems to be a result of this definition so that the equation for species is consistent with bulk mass continuity in Navier-Stokes/Euler equations. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion#Diffusion_coefficient_in_kinetic_theory_of_gases

Comment: Since this is not the actual answer to the question I will leave it as a comment: Chapter 4 of Joel H. Ferziger, H. G. Kaper - Mathematical theory of transport processes in gases covers the answer to my question.

Comment: I stand by what I said.  The term in parenthesis should read $vn_j-nD_j\nabla \omega_j$

Comment: @ChetMiller Shouldn't the diffusion be $n_{j}D_{j}\nabla\omega_{j}$, i.e. $n\rightarrow n_{j}$ in your comment?

Comment: No it shouldn't.  Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: @ChetMiller Lam, Phys. Fluids 18, 073101 (2006), writes the component conservation equation as $\partial\rho_{i}/\partial t+\nabla\cdot(\rho_{i}\vec{V})+\nabla\cdot(\rho_{i}\vec{v}_{i})=S_{i}$ where $\vec V$ is the bulk velocity and $\vec{v}_{i}=\vec{V}_{i}-\vec{V}$ is the diffusion velocity and it has a gradient component $\vec{v}_{i}=-\sum_{j}D_{ij}\nabla\omega_{j}$. Assuming $D_{ij}=D_{i}\delta_{ij}$ and dividing the equation by $m_{i}$ ($\rho_{i}=m_{i}n_{i}$), it seems to me that the diffusion term will have $n_{i}$ instead of $n$.

Comment: I think it makes sense to have $n_{i}$ since $D_{ij}\nabla\omega_{j}$ will be the velocity accounting for the reaction of component $i$ to the inhomogeneity of component $j=1,\ldots,N$ ($\nabla\omega_{j}$). The flux of component $i$'s reaction becomes $n_{i}D_{ij}\nabla\omega_{j}$.

Comment: This makes no sense to me, and is not even correct when j is a trace species.

Comment: @ChetMiller Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136506/discussion-between-newbie-and-chet-miller).

Comment: @ChetMiller If $i$ is a trace species, $\nabla(\omega_{i})=\nabla(\frac{n_{i}}{n})=\frac{\nabla(n_{i})n-\nabla(n)n_{i}}{n^{2}}\simeq \frac{1}{n}\nabla(n_{i})$. Assuming $D_{ij}$ is diagonal, then we have for the diffusion velocity $v_{i}=-D_{ii}\frac{1}{n}\nabla(n_{i})$ so that the diffusion flux is $n_{i}v_{i}=-D_{ii}\frac{n_{i}}{n}\nabla(n_{i})=-D_{ii}\omega_{i}\nabla(n_{i})=-D'_{i}\nabla(n_{i})$. Does this sound ok?

Comment: No.  See Transport Phenomena by Bird et al .

Comment: @ChetMiller Bird equation (24.2-3): $\vec{j}_{\alpha}=\rho_{\alpha}\sum_{\beta}D_{\alpha\beta}\vec{d}_{\beta}-D^{T}_{\alpha}\nabla\ln T$

Comment: It's the same form in equation (6.3-32) of Mathematical Theory of Transport Processes in Gases by Ferziger and Kaper, and Lam, Phys. Fluids 18, 073101 (2006), equation (1a). The term related to density included in $\vec{d}_{j}$ is $\nabla(\omega_{j})$. Therefore, assuming $D_{\alpha\beta}=D_{\alpha}\delta_{\alpha\beta}$ the diffusion current becomes $\vec{j}_{\alpha}=\rho_{\alpha}D_{\alpha}\nabla(\omega_{\alpha})$.

Comment: In Chapter 17, Bird et al give the mass flux of species A in a binary mixture as $\rho_Av-\rho D_{AB}\nabla{\omega_A}$ (Eqns. 17.8-1 and 17.7-3).