# Fluid viscosity, mass diffusion and Navier-Stokes equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, diffusion, viscosity, navier-stokes, convection

With the increase of fluid viscosity, mass diffusion of a fluid decreases. Then how the diffusion term in Navier-Stokes equation has a dominant effect at high viscosity? Also how the mass convection affects the convective term of Navier-Stokes equation?

Comment: There is no mass diffusion term in the standard Navier-Stokes equation.

Comment: @mikestone I suspect OP is questioning the $\nu\nabla^2\mathbf{u}$ term in the NS equations, though if they are considering a multi-component flow, [there surely can be mass diffusion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/194763/25301).