# Equation of Hydrodynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

Please explain this equation from my textbook to me

> - The fundamental equation of hydrodynamics of an ideal fluid (Eulerian equation):$$\rho\frac{\mathrm d \mathbf v}{\mathrm dt}=\mathbf f +\nabla p$$

where $\mathbf f$ represents volume density of mass forces and $\nabla$p is the pressure gradient.

I couldn't find anything related to this formula at  Hyper physics.

Comment: It's just $F=ma$ in a fluid. See [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)).

Comment: How? Where is acceleration ? I don't see acceleration , after checking the dimensions

Comment: $dv/dt$ is acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mike Dunlavey](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/5223/mike-dunlavey) is right in his [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/300482/equation-of-hydrodynamics#comment674782_300482); it's just the Newton's Second Law of Motion.

---

Take a small cube of water. Since, there are no shear forces in a *static* fluid, pressure at any place is same in all directions.

The net force in the cube exerted in the faces perpendicular to $x$ axis parallel to the base of the cube (neglecting higher order derivatives of $p$) is given by $(p - \left(p + \partial_x p~\Delta x\right))\Delta y\Delta z$ where '$\partial_x$' denotes the partial derivative with respect to $x\,.$

Similarly, taking into consideration all the other faces, the resultant force is 
$$-~(\partial_x p + \partial_y p + \partial_z p)~\Delta x\Delta y\Delta z = -~\nabla p ~\Delta x\Delta y\Delta z\,.$$

Then for the cube to be in equilibrium, $$-\nabla p + \mathrm F_\textrm{others} = 0\,.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\textrm{Newton's Second Law of Motion}$$

If the force can be expressed as the gradient of a scalar potential $\varphi,$ per unit mass, then

$$\underbrace{-\nabla p - \rho\nabla \varphi = 0}_\textrm{equation of hydrostatics}\,.\tag{I}$$

(If $\rho$ is constant, then the second term is a pure gradient term. Hence,

$$\begin{align}\nabla(p +\rho\cdot \varphi)  &= 0\\ \implies~~~~~~~~ p + \rho \cdot \varphi &= \textrm{constant} \end{align}$$)

In the general case, the shear stress  is non-zero for there exists *internal force* in the flowing fluid. So, there exists  *viscous* force $\mathbf F_\textrm{viscous force}$. Hence, the equation of motion for an element of fluid per unit volume is given by $$\rho \times (\textrm{acceleration}) = -\nabla p - \rho \nabla \varphi + \mathrm F_\textrm{viscous force} ~~~~\textrm{Newton'
s Second Law of Motion}\tag{II}$$

where

$\begin{align}\textrm{acceleration} \equiv \dot{\mathbf v}(x,y,z,t) & =  v_x ~\partial_x\mathbf v + v_y ~\partial_y \mathbf v  + v_z~\partial_ z \mathbf v + \partial_t \mathbf v \\ & = (\mathbf v\cdot\nabla) ~\mathbf v + \partial_t \mathbf v\tag{III}\,.\end{align}$

Putting $\rm (III)$ in $\rm (II),$ we get

$$\underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbf v}{\partial t} +(\mathbf v\cdot\nabla )~\mathbf v = -\frac{\nabla p}{\rho} -\nabla \varphi + \frac{\mathbf F_\textrm{viscous force}}{\rho}}_\textrm{General equation of motion of a  fluid element per unit volume}\,.\tag{IV}$$

For, ideal "*dry liquid*", $F_\textrm{viscous force} = 0.$ This concludes OP's result as $\rho ~\dot{\mathbf v} = -~\nabla p + \mathbf F ,$ the latter term happens to be conservative in most cases.

---

### References:

$\bullet$ *Lectures on Physics* Vol. 2 by *Feynman, Leighton, Sands*.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, this is [the *Euler equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)); more specifically, the [*incompressible* Euler equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)#Incompressible_Euler_equations). There is a boat-load of information available at the afore-linked Wikipedia entry, as well as on PSE and other sites and books.

The other answer correctly states that this is, "...just the Newton's Second Law of Motion" but I would put forth another, possibly more fundamental, meaning/interpretation to this equation: it is the *conservation of momentum* for the fluid. I go [into the details in this other post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/123744/25301), from which I'll copy some of the relevant details:

> In hydrodynamics, conservation means that what flows into the control volume is equivalent to the flow out of the control volume. With respect to momentum, we mean precisely that
>
> > *any change in momentum of the fluid within a control volume is due to the net flow of fluid into the volume and the action of external forces on the fluid within the volume* ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_dynamics#Conservation_laws))

Which can be mathematically represented as the integrals I give at the link or as the PDE you have (with a minor transformation).

---

I think part of the problem may have been that you seemed to have interpreted the velocity as the *volume*.<sup>1</sup> I think I can understand that thought, given that $M\approx\rho V$. But you should recognize that $\rho$ and $V$ (volume) are *scalar* quantities while the force, $\mathbf f$, and pressure gradient, $\nabla p$, are both *vector* quantities, so the "equation" $scalar\cdot scalar=vector+vector$ cannot hold; so it must be that $\mathbf v$ is also a *vector* quantity with velocity the more logical choice.

<sup>1. The comment in which OP had stated this interpretation of $v$ has since been deleted.</sup>